# Почему не добавляются маршруты через $router.addRoutes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
async loadMenu() {
        try{
            let res = await this.$http.get('/menu')
            this.menuItems = res.data
            res.data.forEach((e) => {
                this.$router.addRoutes([
                    {
                        path: /${e.url},
                        name: ${e.name},
                        component: () => import(`${e.compURL}`)
                    },
                ])
                console.log(e)
            })
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    },
```

не могу понять, почему не добавляет динамические маршруты?

Comment: Непонятно из кода что в вашем понимании не добавляются. Но если моя внутренняя Ванга права, то вот вам 2 ссылки. Вот Issue на эту тему: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2280 . Можно костыльнуть вот так: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1234#issuecomment-357941465

Comment: Спасибо. Не знаю не получается у меня как там написано.

Comment: Мне нужно создать динамически массив объектов routes (path и component)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так переделал, так добавляются маршруты и компоненты, но страница при переходе пустая

```
async loadMenu() {
    try{
        let res = await this.$http.get('/menu')
        this.menuItems = res.data
        res.data.forEach((e) => {
                    this.$router.options.routes.push(
                        {
                            path: `${e.url}`,
                            component: () => import(`${e.compURL}`)

                        }
                    )
            console.log(e)
        })
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
```